# Query para obtener todos los resultados de una tabla añadiendo unos determinado de una segunda tabla relacionada Mysql

Tags: mysql

queria saber si se puede hacer una query o de que forma puedo hacer lo siguiente: 
[image: Tabla games]

[image: tabla users_games]

Tengo estas dos tablas, la segunda esta relacioanda con la primera y otra que se llama usuarios. Lo que quiero es obtener una query que me de como resultado, todos los valores de la primera tabla y que en cada juego aparezca el usuario y el comentario, si es que existe, pero no de todos los usuarios si no de uno en concreto.

Lo que quiero hacer es una pagina con todos los juegos de games y que cada usuario registrado pueda ver si lo tiene añadiso a su libreria y si no que lo pueda añadir, asi como ver el comentario que le haya hecho.

Probe con esta query

SELECT g.game_name, g.type, g.platform, g.image, ug.comment_game, ug.user_name 
FROM games g 
LEFT JOIN users_games ug ON g.game_name= ug.game 
WHERE ug.user_name = 'Crazyloop'

y el resultado fue este

[image: Resultado de la query]

pero lo q quiero es la tabla games con las columnas user_name y comment_game de un usuario determinado en user_name, en cada fila correspondiente del juego. Este es el resultdo  quiero de la query

[image: Resultado q yo quiero]

Muchas gracias y me disculpo por las posibles faltas ortográficas.

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Si las tablas las hiciste vos, como primer medida te dirian que parecerian no ser correctas, ya que muchos de esos campos no deberian tener nombres si no que tendrian que ser referencias a otras tablas. O sea, tus tablas no estan normalizadas, y denota un poco de desconocimiento de db. Sin embargo, lo que queres hacer se puede con un JOIN. Investiga sobre eso, intentalo.

Comment: Gracias por responder. Si estoy verde en esto de las db, hace poco que empece y tengo pendiente profundizar mas por que no se como estructurar las tablas.

Ya he tratado de hacerlo con un JOIN LEFT pero solo consigo q me salgan los que un usuario tiene, no todos los q contiene la tabla games.

Comment: Muestra lo que has intentado entonces.. y que resultado te dio.. y que resultado querias... y es muy importante que leas los enlaces que te pase.. y mucho mas que investigues sobre como diseñar base de datos.. piensa el problema que vas a tener si un usuario quiere cambiar su nombre ;)

Comment: Apenas que especifiques la tabla de usuarios que te falta, y que también especifiques los campos por los cuales se relacionan, que se pudieran presumir a simple vista, pero más vale estar seguro.

Comment: Pone el query, el resultado y lo que eaperabas en la pregunta. Presiona el boton [edit] para editar tu pregunta. Y yo me referia mas a la cantidad de registroa que tenes que tocar para un cambio tan simple ;)

Comment: No encontraba el boton editar por eso no lo hice hay, q me parecia mas logico, por cierto ya le lei las paginas q dijiste. Gracias

Comment: No termino de entender la diferencia entre lo que obtuviste y lo que queres. No agregues imagenes, agrega la info en la pregunta como queres que salga. En el peor de los casos, hace un excel con los datos que queres que salgan y copialos ;).

Comment: El resultado que quieres me parece que va contra las reglas de un diseño de datos estructurado. El problema es que en tus tablas los juegos estarán relacionados con un montón de usuarios en una tabla asociativa, pero tú quieres sí o sí presentar **todos los juegos** *relacionados* con un usuario `X`, incluso aquellos que de hecho no están *relacionados* con ese usuario. No se entiende bien por qué ni para qué, pero da la impresión de que estás enfocando mal la forma en que vas a usar los datos en tu aplicación.

Comment: Es una practica personal y es algo parecido a un portal donde cada usuario puede comentar y guardar en su libreria los juegos q quiera. La idea detras de esto es q haya una pagina con todos los juegos q el usuario pueda visitar, cunado lo haga si ya tiene un juego en la libreria no lo podra añadir de nuevo, al igual q los comentarios, pero alomejor es preferible hacer dos queries diferentes y procesar los datos, si es q la querya asi no es posible

Comment: Si se puede hacer la query que queres.. no es logica, pero se puede. Ahora escribo una respuesta, sin embargo concuerdo con Cedano, algo esta mal en lo que buscas...

Comment: Al leer esto que comentas: *si ya tiene un juego en la libreria no lo podra añadir de nuevo, al igual q los comentarios*  y ver la consulta que quieres hacer para controlar eso (que es en realidad una restricción o *constraint*  en inglés) podemos deducir sin riesgo a equivocarnos que estás enfocando muy mal la solución del problema. Cuando quieres impedir que haya datos repetidos en las tablas debes resolverlo ante todo mediante restricciones (constraint). En este caso, lo que aplicaría sería una restricción `UNIQUE` que abarque las columnas `user_id, game_id`...

Comment: ... por cierto, conviene que, para las relaciones, uses las columnas de id en vez de columnas como `user_name`. Las relaciones funcionan mucho mejor así: rapidez, menos espacio de almacenamiento, menos riesgo de error, etc.

Comment: Lo se pero me resulta mas facil de seguir los datos de esta manera, es el primer proyecto q hago usando bbdd y con un conocimiento bastante limitado al respecto, la verdad es q agradezco muchisimo vuesta ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos a obviar los claros problemas que tienen estas tablas, como la falta de normalización.

Mas allá de eso, ese query que quieres se puede hacer de la siguiente manera. Necesitamos unir la tabla de juegos, con un pedazo de la tabla de usuarios.

De la tabla de usuarios queremos:

```
Select * 
from users_games 
where user_name = 'Crazyloop'
```

Esta tabla, solo trae los juegos de ese usuario, y ahora si, podemos hacer un left join con la tabla de juegos, usando como entrada la tabla de juegos:

```
SELECT g.game_name, g.type, g.platform, g.image, ug.comment_game, ug.user_name 
FROM games g LEFT JOIN (todo el query anterior) ug ON g.game_name= ug.game
```

Esto va a funcionar, porque la tabla anterior solo tiene los registros de ese usuario, o sea es un subset de esa tabla.

Igual, vuelvo a insistir. Todas estas tablas parecen estar mal, y es muy importante que leas respecto a normalización. Sin embargo, el query que vos queres no esta mal, ni es ilogico...

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, lo he probado y me da el resultado que esperaba, solo has tenido un fallo en la primera querry con ----- ug.user_name = 'Crazyloop'------ que no deberia llevar la ug delante. Me pondre a estudiar MySQL cuando saque tiempo. Muchas gracias de nuevo

Comment: Corregido! Y no tenes que estudiar mysql.. tenes que estudiar base de datos..